# The jenkins pipeline send email error with “java.lang.NoSuchMethodError”。

Tags: java, jenkins

when i use pipeline to send email, the Jenkins Console Output **"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError"**,
I think this may be caused by the mailer plugin or the Jenkins version ,But I'm not sure，so i How to do it?

pipeline

```
  pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
            stage('Hello') {
                steps {
                    echo "Hello world"
                        }
                }
            }
        post{
            always{
                mail to: "15283666096@163.com",
                subject: "Test Email",
                body: "Test"
            }
        }
    }
```

output

```
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] mail
Error when executing always post condition:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'jenkins.plugins.mailer.tasks.MimeMessageBuilder jenkins.plugins.mailer.tasks.MimeMessageBuilder.addRecipients(java.lang.String, javax.mail.Message$RecipientType)'
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MailStep$MailStepExecution.buildMimeMessage(MailStep.java:167)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MailStep$MailStepExecution.run(MailStep.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MailStep$MailStepExecution.run(MailStep.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]. [Edit] your question and add a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an updated version of **Mailer** and an older version of **Pipeline Basic Steps**.

The problem is in the call to **Mailer** from the **Pipeline Basic Steps** plugin.

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MailStep$MailStepExecution.buildMimeMessage(MailStep.java:167)
```

In this [commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/commit/d2ef6c4f16d6d7b430e9edb162b93de1f6ad6b46), they migrate from *javax.mail* to *jakarta.mail*.

So, older versions of **Pipeline Basic Steps** make the call with the argument of type `javax.mail.Message$RecipientType` instead of `jakarta.mail.Message$RecipientType`.

Here a recent version of the class [MimeMessageBuilder](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mailer-plugin/blob/448.v5b_97805e3767/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/mailer/tasks/MimeMessageBuilder.java) with the method `addRecipients(java.lang.String, jakarta.mail.Message$RecipientType)`.

I updated the **Pipeline** plugin that has the **Pipeline Basic Steps** dependency, to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [following documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#mail-mail), there is no "`mail to`" attribute for mail plugin.

Can you try the same configuration with "`to`" attribute instead of "`mail to`"?